# Como estruturar os parâmetros num objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 var colHeaders = [
    "Column 1",
    "Column 2"
];

var columns = [
    {data: 'column_1', validator: validatorRentalCode, allowEmpty: false, allowInvalid: false},
    {data: 'column_2', type: 'numeric', numericFormat: typeNumber, allowEmpty: false},
];

var options = {
    columns: columns,
    colHeaders: colHeaders
};
div = document.querySelector('#table');
var table = new Table(div, options);
```

Como as variáveis fazem parte do contexto do Objeto Table. Gostaria de melhorar e transformar as variáveis em parâmetros conforme abaixo:

```
var Table = {
    TABLE: {
        HEADERS: [
            "Column 1",
            "Column 2"
        ],
        COLUMNS: [
            {data: 'horas_extras', type: 'time', timeFormat: 'hh:mm', correctFormat: true, allowEmpty: false}
        ]
    },
    OPTIONS: {
        columns: this.TABLE.COLUMNS,
        colHeaders: this.TABLE.HEADERS
    }
};
```

Nesta minha alteração acabou ocorrendo um `undefined`: `Cannot read property 'COLUMNS' of undefined`. Por ter um conhecimento básico na linguagem, acredito que a propriedade `COLUMNS` não exista no momento da criação do objeto.

Qual seria a melhor forma de resolver este meu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o que está dando undefined seria seu this.TABLE pois quando executado o this dentro do seu objeto ele está pegando o escopo de fora, e não do objeto.

Uma tratativa válida seria:

```
var gerarTable = function () {

    var columns = [{data: 'horas_extras', type: 'time', timeFormat: 'hh:mm', correctFormat: true, allowEmpty: false}];
    var headers = ["Column 1","Column 2"];

    return {
        TABLE: {
            HEADERS: headers,
            COLUMNS: columns
        },
        OPTIONS: {
            columns: columns,
            colHeaders: headers
        }
    };
};
```

e ao executar ele te retorna a Table:

```
var Table = gerarTable();
```

Uma dica minha é abrir o console do navegador (F12) e começar a brincar no console com os códigos javascript, ele tem acesso ao javascript da página.